# Statically partitioning the slaves in a mesos marathon cluster

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

We have multiple kinds of applications running on the same Mesos-Marathon cluster. The applications can be classified into very loosely coupled categories and can almost run separately. They are running on the same cluster considering the easiness to provision, maintenance of the cluster, re-use of CI/CD pipelines etc. 
However, is there a mechanism to statically partition the number of slaves in the cluster so that a group of these applications are provisioned on a set of slaves and the other group on another set.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Mesos custom [attributes](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/attributes-resources/) for that which in turn get used by Marathon via constraints.

From the [Marathon documentation on constraints](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/docs/docs/constraints.md):

> Constraints control where apps run to allow optimizing for either
>   fault tolerance (by spreading a task out on multiple nodes) or
>   locality (by running all of an applications tasks on the same node).
>   Constraints have three parts: a field name, an operator, and an
>   optional parameter. The field can be the hostname of the agent node or
>   any attribute of the agent node.